# Problems with editing C++ QList<Object*> model in Qml code and some Qml warnings

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols

I need to create a model that can be edited in C++ and Qml code. This model will be used in an desktop application that contains both Qt Widgets and Qml. For qml rendering I use the `QQuickWidget`.

I have data object with two properties: name and color.

dataobject.h

```
#ifndef DATAOBJECT_H
#define DATAOBJECT_H

#include <QObject>

class DataObject : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(QString name READ name WRITE setName NOTIFY nameChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString color READ color WRITE setColor NOTIFY colorChanged)

public:
    DataObject(QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR);
    DataObject(const QString &name, const QString &color, QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR);

    QString name() const;
    void setName(const QString &name);

    QString color() const;
    void setColor(const QString &color);

signals:
    void nameChanged();
    void colorChanged();

private:
    QString m_name;
    QString m_color;
};

#endif // DATAOBJECT_H
```

dataobject.cpp

```
#include "dataobject.h"

#include <QDebug>

DataObject::DataObject(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent)
{
}

DataObject::DataObject(const QString &name, const QString &color, QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent), m_name(name), m_color(color)
{
}

QString DataObject::name() const
{
    return m_name;
}

void DataObject::setName(const QString &name)
{
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO;

    if (name != m_name) {
        m_name = name;
        emit nameChanged();
    }
}

QString DataObject::color() const
{
    return m_color;
}

void DataObject::setColor(const QString &color)
{
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO;

    if (color != m_color) {
        m_color = color;
        emit colorChanged();
    }
}
```

For the main window I use subclass of `QMainWindow`. Сentral widget contains `QQuickWidget` with source MainView.qml. In constructor I fill `QList<Object*>` model and set it as context property "nameColorModel" for MainView.qml.

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);
    ~MainWindow();

public slots:
    void onAccepted();

private:
    QList<QObject*> nameColorModel;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "dataobject.h"

#include <QQuickWidget>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QQuickItem>

#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    auto qmlWidget = new QQuickWidget(QUrl("qrc:/MainView.qml"), this);
    qmlWidget->setResizeMode(QQuickWidget::SizeRootObjectToView);

    this->setCentralWidget(qmlWidget);
    this->resize(600, 400);

    nameColorModel.append(new DataObject("Item 1", "red"));
    nameColorModel.append(new DataObject("Item 2", "green"));
    nameColorModel.append(new DataObject("Item 3", "blue"));
    nameColorModel.append(new DataObject("Item 4", "yellow"));

    qmlWidget->rootContext()->setContextProperty("nameColorModel", QVariant::fromValue(nameColorModel));

    connect(qmlWidget->rootObject(), SIGNAL(accepted()), SLOT(onAccepted()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    qDeleteAll(nameColorModel.begin(), nameColorModel.end());
}

void MainWindow::onAccepted()
{
    for(auto& object: nameColorModel)
    {
        auto item = qobject_cast<DataObject*>(object);
        qDebug() << item->name() << item->color();
    }
}
```

MainView.qml contains some additional components (firstTextField, secondComboBox, "Ok" and "Cancel" buttons) and `GroupBox` containing `Repeater` which uses my "nameColorModel". NameColorEdit.qml is used as delegate of `Repeater`.

MainView.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

import "." as Views

Item {
    id: root
    width: 600
    height: 400

    property alias firstText: firstTextField.text
    property alias secondText: secondComboBox.currentText

    signal accepted()
    signal rejected()

    ColumnLayout {
        spacing: 10
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 10

        GridLayout {
            columns: 2
            rowSpacing: 10
            columnSpacing: 10

            Label {
                text: "First"
            }

            TextField {
                id: firstTextField
                implicitHeight: 42
                Layout.fillWidth: true
            }

            Label {
                text: "Second"
            }

            ComboBox {
                id: secondComboBox
                implicitHeight: 42
                model: 5
                Layout.fillWidth: true
            }
        }

        GroupBox {
            title: qsTr("Name-color objects:")
            Layout.fillWidth: true

            ColumnLayout {
                id: col
                spacing: 10
                anchors.fill: parent

                Repeater {
                    id: repeater
                    model: nameColorModel ////  <-- QList<Object*> model

                    Views.NameColorEdit {
                        name: modelData.name
                        color: modelData.color
                        Layout.row: index
                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Item {
            Layout.fillHeight: true
        }

        RowLayout {
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignRight

            Button {
                text: "Ок"
                Layout.minimumWidth: 42
                Layout.minimumHeight: 42
                onClicked: accepted()
            }

            Button {
                text: "Cancel"
                Layout.minimumWidth: 42
                Layout.minimumHeight: 42
                onClicked: rejected()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

NameColorEdit.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

Item {
    id: root
    implicitWidth: nameField.implicitWidth
    implicitHeight: nameField.implicitHeight

    property alias name: nameField.text
    property alias color: colorField.text

    RowLayout {
        spacing: 10
        anchors.fill: parent

        Label {
            text: "Color"
        }

        TextField {
            id: colorField
            enabled: false
            implicitWidth: 150
            implicitHeight: 42
        }

        Label {
            text: "Name"
        }

        TextField {
            id: nameField
            implicitHeight: 42
            Layout.fillWidth: true
        }
    }
}
```

When I change text in the "nameField" of NameColorEdit.qml, "nameColorModel" doesn't change in С++ code. 
How can I fix this?

Also there are following warnings in qml code:

> qrc:/MainView.qml:50:9: QML GroupBox: Binding loop detected for
>   property "implicitWidth" qrc:/MainView.qml:61: ReferenceError:
>   nameColorModel is not defined

Note that the model will be set after calling setSource of `QQuickWidget`.
How can I fix these warnings?

You can also give me recommendations on writing code.

Thank you!

Comment: Your view is created before the context property is set, so the first run will complain about nameColorModel. Try setting the contextproperty earlier.

Comment: You might also want to consider to have a "data handler" class that manages your value pairs and provides signals for change notification and use that in a table model for QtWidgets and a list model for QtQuick.

Alternatively a table model for both cases but which maps the QML properties into columns

Comment: @arynaq, Is there a way to set context properties after view creation without warnings?

Comment: @Kevin Krammer, Thanks for the recommendation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by using `Binding` for `DataObject` property and `NameColorEdit` property:

```
        Repeater {
            id: repeater
            model: nameColorModel ////  <-- QList<Object*> model

            Views.NameColorEdit {
                name: modelData.name
                color: modelData.color
                Layout.row: index
                Layout.fillWidth: true

                Binding { target: modelData; property: "name"; value: name }
                Binding { target: modelData; property: "color"; value: color }
            }
        }
```

Now, when editing nameField in NameColorEdit.qml content of `QList<Object*>` model in C++ code is successfully updated. Also, If we change content of `QList<Object*>` model in C++ code, NameColorEdit.qml will be updated.